# gitのローカルリポジトリの外部化をしたい

Tags: git

git branch -b develop origin/develop
git commit -m "ほげほげ"
などとしたときに、対象となるローカルリポジトリを ~/.gitでなく、外部化する方法はありますでしょうか？

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`--separate-git-dir`を使ってみてください。
`git 1.7.5`以上が必要です。

Comment: ありがとうございます！助かりました！